# REST-based file server

Tags: http, server-message-block, file-server

I need to be able to PUT files and GET them later using nothing but HTTP, so I went searching for something that might match the terms "REST file server" or "HTTP file server" or "REST drop-box", etc. Unfortunately, these terms bring up the wrong kind of results on Google.

What I want is the equivalent of an SMB fileshare over HTTP. Some ideal features:

- Can PUT a file of any type at http://servername/service/any/path/I/want/document.pdf
- Anyone with access can GET that file at the URL I PUT it at
- Supports AV scanning on any new file that has been PUT
- Supports DELETE of existing resources (files)

Our shop runs Windows, but I'd be interested to know about Unix software that can do this kind of thing, too.

It's to be used in an IT department for private users only. It won't be on a public-facing IP address.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  As far as I know, WebDAV is designed to work like a filesystem, over HTTP.

For Apache there is mod_dav, and from a quick check on the Interwebs, IIS has it built-in, somehow.

Maybe WebDAV is something that could help you.

-Chris

Comment: WebDAV for IIS is a separate, free download from MS.

Comment: But difficult to setup. I have tried a few times and failed.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.org) is a [nosql database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosql) accessed by HTTP methods. You can store files of any type and retrieve them (for example, using `curl`).

Unfortunately, it would be difficult to scan them for viruses (maybe a map function using an online AV like [virustotal](http://www.virustotal.com)).